# Why transferred bytes are bigger than size bytes in firefox dev tools?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

I am measuring the performance from a website. When looking at the firefox-developer-tools, I noticed a weird behavior. There is a specific JS file which the transferred size is 2,831.54 KB, but the actual size is 1280kb.

[image: Image of Firefox dev-tools with the description]

[According to Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor), the Transferred size should be smaller or equals to Size:

> **Transferred (new in Firefox 38)**: the number of bytes that were
>   actually transferred to load the resource. This will be less than Size
>   if the resource was compressed.
>
> **Size**: the size of the resource, after
>   any decompression.

Firefox Developer Edition version: 41.0a2 (2015-07-19)

What could have caused this behavior?

Comment: Can you provide a public URLs for this resource I can use to replicate this and log a bug?

Comment: Hi @canuckistani. Sorry for taking a long time to answer. Is there a way to send that to you in private? :)

Comment: Sure, jgriffiths at mozilla dot com

Comment: As a follow-up, Mario gave me a url to test and I saw an odd effect - a specific file where the transferred size was much larger than the actual size. When I used wget or curl I got the same size in the content length header. Chrome reported the same size. Then I copied the file off of of the server to a different server hosted by [surge.sh](https://surge.sh) and saw completely different ( and much more normal ) transferred / real sizes reported by all tools used. I suspect this is a server configuration / http quirk.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solutions yet?

Comment: Not really. I haven't investigated further, but it seems something wrong either in the server or in Firefox itself. When using wget or curl the result is displayed correctly, so we don't know

Comment: @canuckistani Here is a public URL which exhibits this issue (jpg): https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/Peshmerga_on_a_T-55-Tank_outside_Kirkuk_in_Iraq..jpg

Comment: Thanks, logged [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1219556)

Comment: FWIW this bug has been fixed and the fix will appear in Firefox 52.

Comment: The incorrect sizes appear to happen in my development JavaScript builds, but in production mode, the numbers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the most upvoted [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508885/why-transferred-bytes-are-bigger-than-size-bytes-in-firefox-dev-tools#comment71618111_31508885) on the question:

This appears to be a rare bug in Firefox that has been fixed in Firefox 52:

> FWIW this bug has been fixed and the fix will appear in Firefox 52.
>
> – Tom Tromey Feb 14 '17 at 14:59

Comment: As of 90.0.2, I can still see `transferred > size`

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 107.0. Still the same bug.